# Voice-over-IP with a VPN

Tags: iptables, openvpn, vpn, voip, sip

I use an IPFire (linux) router as a VPN client. My voice-over-IP is working properly without the VPN active. However, when the VPN is up, my SIP client (Twinkle) can't register with my VoIP provider. Normally, my VPN is up all the time. So I need to make VoIP work with the VPN.

```
uname -a
Linux ipfire 3.14.65-ipfire #1 SMP Wed May 4 03:06:53 GMT 2016 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

VPN is by privateinternetaccess.com.

I start my VPN client with:

```
modprobe tun
openvpn --config /var/ipfire/ovpn/my_vpn.conf --daemon
```

The port forwarding settings I am using are:

```
On  Proto   Src     Port        Destination    Description
On  UDP     RED     5060        192.168.1.1     SIP_voip
On  TCP     RED     5060        192.168.1.1     SIP_voip
On  UDP     RED     8000        192.168.1.1     SIP_twinkle_RTP
On  UDP     RED     8001        192.168.1.1     SIP_twinkle_RTP
On  UDP     RED     8002        192.168.1.1     SIP_twinkle_RTP
On  UDP     RED     8003        192.168.1.1     SIP_twinkle_RTP
On  UDP     RED     8004        192.168.1.1     SIP_twinkle_RTP
On  UDP     RED     8005        192.168.1.1     SIP_twinkle_RTP
```

Here are my openvpn client settings:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote example.com
port 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ca /var/ipfire/ovpn/ca.crt
tls-client
remote-cert-tls server
auth-user-pass
comp-lzo
verb 1
reneg-sec 0
crl-verify /var/ipfire/ovpn/crl.pem
ping 15
ping-restart 45
```

iptables rules ($ sudo iptables -S):

```
-P INPUT DROP
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N BADTCP
-N CONNTRACK
-N CUSTOMFORWARD
-N CUSTOMINPUT
-N CUSTOMOUTPUT
-N DHCPBLUEINPUT
-N DHCPBLUEOUTPUT
-N DHCPGREENINPUT
-N DHCPGREENOUTPUT
-N DHCPINPUT
-N DHCPOUTPUT
-N FORWARDFW
-N GEOIPBLOCK
-N GUARDIAN
-N GUIINPUT
-N ICMPINPUT
-N INPUTFW
-N IPSECBLOCK
-N IPSECFORWARD
-N IPSECINPUT
-N IPSECOUTPUT
-N IPTVFORWARD
-N IPTVINPUT
-N LOG_DROP
-N LOG_REJECT
-N LOOPBACK
-N NEWNOTSYN
-N OUTGOINGFW
-N OVPNBLOCK
-N OVPNINPUT
-N P2PBLOCK
-N POLICYFWD
-N POLICYIN
-N POLICYOUT
-N PSCAN
-N REDFORWARD
-N REDINPUT
-N TOR_INPUT
-N UPNPFW
-N WIRELESSFORWARD
-N WIRELESSINPUT
-A INPUT -p tcp -j BADTCP
-A INPUT -j CUSTOMINPUT
-A INPUT -j P2PBLOCK
-A INPUT -j GUARDIAN
-A INPUT -i tun+ -j OVPNBLOCK
-A INPUT -j IPTVINPUT
-A INPUT -j ICMPINPUT
-A INPUT -j LOOPBACK
-A INPUT -j CONNTRACK
-A INPUT -i green0 -j DHCPGREENINPUT
-A INPUT -i blue0 -j DHCPBLUEINPUT
-A INPUT -j GEOIPBLOCK
-A INPUT -j IPSECINPUT
-A INPUT -j GUIINPUT
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j WIRELESSINPUT
-A INPUT -j OVPNINPUT
-A INPUT -j TOR_INPUT
-A INPUT -j INPUTFW
-A INPUT -j REDINPUT
-A INPUT -j POLICYIN
-A FORWARD -p tcp -j BADTCP
-A FORWARD -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -j TCPMSS --clamp-mss-to-pmtu
-A FORWARD -j CUSTOMFORWARD
-A FORWARD -j P2PBLOCK
-A FORWARD -j GUARDIAN
-A FORWARD -m policy --dir out --pol none -j IPSECBLOCK
-A FORWARD -i tun+ -j OVPNBLOCK
-A FORWARD -o tun+ -j OVPNBLOCK
-A FORWARD -j IPTVFORWARD
-A FORWARD -j LOOPBACK
-A FORWARD -j CONNTRACK
-A FORWARD -j GEOIPBLOCK
-A FORWARD -j IPSECFORWARD
-A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j WIRELESSFORWARD
-A FORWARD -j FORWARDFW
-A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j UPNPFW
-A FORWARD -j REDFORWARD
-A FORWARD -j POLICYFWD
-A OUTPUT -j CUSTOMOUTPUT
-A OUTPUT -j P2PBLOCK
-A OUTPUT -m policy --dir out --pol none -j IPSECBLOCK
-A OUTPUT -j LOOPBACK
-A OUTPUT -j CONNTRACK
-A OUTPUT -o green0 -j DHCPGREENOUTPUT
-A OUTPUT -o blue0 -j DHCPBLUEOUTPUT
-A OUTPUT -j IPSECOUTPUT
-A OUTPUT -j OUTGOINGFW
-A OUTPUT -j POLICYOUT
-A BADTCP -i lo -j RETURN
-A BADTCP -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG FIN,PSH,URG -j PSCAN
-A BADTCP -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG FIN,SYN,RST,ACK,URG -j PSCAN
-A BADTCP -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG -j PSCAN
-A BADTCP -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG FIN -j PSCAN
-A BADTCP -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN,RST -j PSCAN
-A BADTCP -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN FIN,SYN -j PSCAN
-A BADTCP -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG NONE -j PSCAN
-A BADTCP -p tcp -m tcp ! --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j NEWNOTSYN
-A CONNTRACK -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A CONNTRACK -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A CONNTRACK -p icmp -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A CONNTRACK -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED -m helper --helper sip -j ACCEPT
-A CONNTRACK -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED -m helper --helper h323 -j ACCEPT
-A CONNTRACK -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED -m helper --helper ftp -m tcp --dport 1024:65535 -j ACCEPT
-A CONNTRACK -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED -m helper --helper irc -j ACCEPT
-A DHCPBLUEINPUT -i blue0 -j DHCPINPUT
-A DHCPBLUEOUTPUT -o blue0 -j DHCPOUTPUT
-A DHCPGREENINPUT -i green0 -j DHCPINPUT
-A DHCPGREENOUTPUT -o green0 -j DHCPOUTPUT
-A DHCPINPUT -p udp -m udp --sport 68 --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A DHCPINPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 68 --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A DHCPOUTPUT -p udp -m udp --sport 67 --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
-A DHCPOUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 67 --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARDFW -d 192.168.1.1/32 -i red0 -p udp -m udp --dport 5060 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARDFW -d 192.168.1.1/32 -i red0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5060 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARDFW -d 192.168.1.1/32 -i red0 -p udp -m udp --dport 8000 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARDFW -d 192.168.1.1/32 -i red0 -p udp -m udp --dport 8001 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARDFW -d 192.168.1.1/32 -i red0 -p udp -m udp --dport 8002 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARDFW -d 192.168.1.1/32 -i red0 -p udp -m udp --dport 8003 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARDFW -d 192.168.1.1/32 -i red0 -p udp -m udp --dport 8004 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARDFW -d 192.168.1.1/32 -i red0 -p udp -m udp --dport 8005 -j ACCEPT
-A GUIINPUT -i green0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 444 -j ACCEPT
-A ICMPINPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUTFW -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 192.168.1.251/32 -i green0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUTFW -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 192.168.1.251/32 -i green0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUTFW -s 192.168.2.0/24 -d 192.168.2.250/32 -i blue0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUTFW -s 192.168.2.0/24 -d 192.168.2.250/32 -i blue0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUTFW -d 10.0.0.114/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m limit --limit 10/min --limit-burst 20 -j LOG --log-prefix "INPUTFW "
-A INPUTFW -d 10.0.0.114/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j DROP
-A LOG_DROP -m limit --limit 10/min -j LOG
-A LOG_DROP -j DROP
-A LOG_REJECT -m limit --limit 10/min -j LOG
-A LOG_REJECT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A LOOPBACK -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A LOOPBACK -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A LOOPBACK -s 127.0.0.0/8 -j DROP
-A LOOPBACK -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j DROP
-A NEWNOTSYN -m comment --comment DROP_NEWNOTSYN -j DROP
-A OVPNBLOCK -p icmp -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED -j RETURN
-A POLICYFWD -s 192.168.1.0/24 -i green0 -j ACCEPT
-A POLICYFWD -m policy --dir in --pol ipsec -j ACCEPT
-A POLICYFWD -i tun+ -j ACCEPT
-A POLICYFWD -s 192.168.2.0/24 -i blue0 -o red0 -j ACCEPT
-A POLICYFWD -s 192.168.3.0/24 -i orange0 -o red0 -j ACCEPT
-A POLICYFWD -m limit --limit 10/min -j LOG --log-prefix "DROP_FORWARD "
-A POLICYFWD -m comment --comment DROP_FORWARD -j DROP
-A POLICYIN -i green0 -j ACCEPT
-A POLICYIN -i blue0 -j ACCEPT
-A POLICYIN -m policy --dir in --pol ipsec -j ACCEPT
-A POLICYIN -i tun+ -j ACCEPT
-A POLICYIN -m limit --limit 10/min -j LOG --log-prefix "DROP_INPUT "
-A POLICYIN -m comment --comment DROP_INPUT -j DROP
-A POLICYOUT -j ACCEPT
-A POLICYOUT -m comment --comment DROP_OUTPUT -j DROP
-A PSCAN -p tcp -m limit --limit 10/min -m comment --comment "DROP_TCP PScan" -j LOG --log-prefix "DROP_TCP Scan "
-A PSCAN -p udp -m limit --limit 10/min -m comment --comment "DROP_UDP PScan" -j LOG --log-prefix "DROP_UDP Scan "
-A PSCAN -p icmp -m limit --limit 10/min -m comment --comment "DROP_ICMP PScan" -j LOG --log-prefix "DROP_ICMP Scan "
-A PSCAN -f -m limit --limit 10/min -m comment --comment "DROP_FRAG PScan" -j LOG --log-prefix "DROP_FRAG Scan "
-A PSCAN -m comment --comment DROP_PScan -j DROP
-A REDFORWARD -i orange0 -o red0 -j ACCEPT
-A REDINPUT -i red0 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 67 --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
-A REDINPUT -i red0 -p udp -m udp --sport 67 --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
-A WIRELESSFORWARD -s 192.168.2.1/32 -i blue0 -m mac --mac-source XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX -j RETURN
-A WIRELESSFORWARD -i blue0 -j LOG --log-prefix DROP_Wirelessforward
-A WIRELESSFORWARD -i blue0 -m comment --comment DROP_Wirelessforward -j DROP
-A WIRELESSINPUT -s 192.168.2.1/32 -i blue0 -m mac --mac-source XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX -j RETURN
-A WIRELESSINPUT -i blue0 -j LOG --log-prefix DROP_Wirelessinput
-A WIRELESSINPUT -i blue0 -m comment --comment DROP_Wirelessinput -j DROP
```

$ sudo route -n:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.157.1.5      128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
0.0.0.0         10.0.0.1        0.0.0.0         UG    204    0        0 red0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     204    0        0 red0
10.157.1.1      10.157.1.5      255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 tun0
10.157.1.5      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
129.82.205.12   10.0.0.1        255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 red0
128.0.0.0       10.157.1.5      128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.1.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 green0
192.168.2.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 blue0
```

Comment: What does your routing table look like with the vpn running?

Comment: I added the ouput of sudo route -n. Do you need to see anything else? Thanks

Comment: Partition the problem. If you switch off your firewall and reset the policies to `ACCEPT` does it work?

Comment: Which network name is external facing, and which one is your VoIP client on?

Comment: @roaima - Earlier I tested by putting the host (the computer with the SIP client) in a DMZ. It did not resolve the issue. (I do not see a clean way to completely disable the firewall in IPFire. I'm new to IPFire. I'll have to ask on their forum.)

Comment: @roaima - In IPFire, red0 is external (WAN). The openvpn client is running on the IPFire box.

Comment: In IPFire, red is external interface (WAN), green is LAN (wired), and blue is wireless LAN, orange is DMZ.

Comment: @roaima "So where is your VoIP client?" I don't understand the question, sorry. I thought I gave enough info in the question. If you have a command you want me to run, I'll run it and paste the output.

Comment: Green. The VoIP client connects to the green interface. Sorry for not understanding when you asked previously. (I read it as VPN client.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your rules don't make sense for the scenario you've described.

I'll accept that the `CONNTRACK` chain handles the VPN inbound packets, so your VPN will work.

However, if you want VoIP to run over the VPN then you don't need any rules at all on `red0` that handle SIP traffic.

It looks like you want to accepting unregistered SIP calls in to your public IP address, but your traffic flow is outbound via the VPN. That will confuse the caller because the outbound IP address won't match the called target address.

Again, in the usual way of running a SIP client it would register to an endpoint/proxy and so you wouldn't need any rules other than a generic *ACCEPT RELATED* to permit the traffic to flow correctly. (You might need to declare the public IP address in Twinkle; that depends on how well it can use STUN or ICE to find it out.)

At this point I would strongly urge you to turn off the firewall temporarily, reset the INPUT, OUTPUT, FORWARD chain policies to ACCEPT, and see if it works. Then you can start applying firewall rules.

Comment: Thanks for that feedback. I removed the unneeded rules. It turns out that my VPN provider started blocking VoIP. I switched VPN providers today and my setup is working again.

Answer (score 2):

Your routing table shows that the VPN is set up to redirect *all* traffic through the VPN. This can cause issues in several ways:

- if you registered to the SIP service before starting the VPN, then once you start the VPN, the SIP traffic will appear to be coming from a different sender, as far as your SIP provider is concerned. To avoid this problem, make sure you do the SIP registration only when the VPN is already running.
- if the other side of the VPN doesn't do proper NAT of your SIP traffic, then this cannot possibly work.
- Due to the fact that the route to your SIP provider is going to be much longer this way, your SIP traffic will be somewhat delayed. This may cause issues with your SIP connection, too.

The last part there is valid for more than just your SIP connection; e.g., if you want to play games, or watch Netflix, or do any of a number of other things which benefit from high bandwidth and/or low latency, this setup *will* cause problems. In addition, whoever provides the end point for your VPN is capable of reading *all* your (unencrypted) traffic. Ask yourself whether you really need to do this...

Comment: Would you be so kind as to further explain, "if the other side of the VPN doesn't do proper NAT of your SIP traffic, then this cannot possibly work."

Comment: My VoIP call quality is actually superior when it goes over a VPN. That is based on my experience with my old router (prior to using IPFire). Now the IPFire router is much faster. I do want to route all traffic over the VPN. The VPN has good performance in general. The VPN great for everything I do including Netflix.

Comment: You may to say it used to work with the same VPN but a different router? In that case the comment on NAT is irrelevant.

Comment: VoIP over VPN worked with a different router. I can't remember if I was using the same or a different VPN provider at that time. I was using the same VoIP provider and in general all my settings are the same as when it worked. The router is new and, as I said, I can't remember if the VPN provider is the same.